# How to make agents search for patches they havent been to Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I want to make and eagle fly through this map. However, the eagle just flies by the edges of the map. The edge is anything that's not black.

I tried

```
ask patches [ ifelse pcolor != 0 and pxcor > 350 or pxcor < 100 [set edge 1][set edge 0 ]]

ask Buteo-platypterus [face max-one-of patches with [edge = 1] [distance myself] fd 5]
```

This makes them go to the edge, but they don't move. I thought that by asking for the max it would always move to the furthest edge, but it didnt. The idea is that the bird goes from edge to edge, say like a ping pong, where as soon as they reach the topmost point they go down and vice-versa.

The birds start at a random point on the map, so the most first reach the edge of the map, any edge, and then do the ping pong thing.

[image: Image of the map and the birds]

*Edited to fix formating*

[image: Edit2: Show patches that are considered edge]

Answer (score 1):

In a model I am myself working on, I use a turtles-own agentset to remember all the patches they have already visited. Before each move, they add the current patch they are on, and then look for the nearest patch that they haven't visited yet.

```
turtles-own [patch-memory]

to setup
    ask turtles [set patch-memory [] ] ;Only do this to initiate the list, or when you intentionally want to forget everything that was in here
end

to go
    ask turtles [
       set patch-memory lput patch-here patch-memory
       move-to min-one-of patches with [ not member? self [patch-memory] of myself] [distance myself]
    ]
end
```

Edit: Do note that this can be quite slow if you have a lot of turtles and a lot of patches, but it is the concept that counts here.

Comment: Leirs! thanks for your answer. This is useful for another thing that im planning, however, i dont know how this can help me move my bird like a ping pong. Thanks to your correcion the map now is shown propertly. The bird need should be able to go up and down from anywhere on the right part of the map (that grey area). Thanks Again

Comment: I see now. So you actually want the pingpong effect? Well in that case the first thing to do is check which of your patches actually have edge set to 1, since I believe your logic in there is a bit flawed. Try `ask patches [ with edge = 1] [set pcolor red]` to quickly see what patches actually have this changed edge.

Comment: Added the map to show the "edge" its a little too big tho. The idea is that first the birds reach the red part, as the spawn anywhere. Then, the go from edge to edge, top to bottom. thanks again.

Comment: Leirs! hello. I did a small change thats, 
  ask Buteo-platypterus[if [target= 0] of patch-here [face  one-of patches with [ target= 1] fd 1 set energia energia - 1]]; 200
  ask Buteo-platypterus[if [objetivo = 1] of patch-here [face  one-of patches with [ target= 2] fd 2 set energia energia - 1]]

The problem is that as soon as they leave the target one, they go back, naturally, but i dont know how to fix it. What do you think?

Comment: Hello. I also tried to adapt your code 
 ask Anas-discors [if [pcolor = 88] of patch-here [set memory lput patch-here memory
    face min-one-of patches with [ not member? self [memory] of myself and pcolor = 88] [distance myself] fd 1]]

I did this so only the patches of that color are in memory, but im getting an error.

Comment: LPUT expected input to be a list but got the number 0 instead.
error while anas-disc 35 running LPUT

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response. In trying to be concise, I omitted an important part. When working with a list like this, you should first initialise an empty list by doing `ask turtles [set patch-memory [] ]`. From then on, you can use primitives like `lput` to manipulate the list. It is important to only do this once (at setup, at birth, or at a reset), since each time you do this your turtles "forget" everything.

Comment: Where exactly do they go back to?

Comment: Since you are working with small steps, you want your birds to commit to a direction until they reach their destination. The code you put down in your followup question is not extremely clear, but if i had to guess it would be that you didn't assign each patch a `target` value. In such cases, Netlogo defaults to a value of 0. That means that as soon as your bird steps onto an unassigned patch, it will move back towards the patch with "target = 1"